# wso2 Login failed.Insufficient privileges

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new with API Management tools. After installing WSO2 i tried the samples but I am not able to login into the publisher and store. I just get an error message stating:

Login failed.Insufficient Privileges.

The console give me the following output:

```
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,196]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2014-06-10 15:44:41,195+0200]
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,196]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2014-06-10 15:44:41,0196] from IP address 10þ.109.63.143 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,197] ERROR - AUDIT_LOG Illegal access attempt at [2014-06-10 15:44:41,0196] from IP address 10.109.63.143 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,212]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2014-06-10 15:44:41,212+0200]
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,213]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2014-06-10 15:44:41,0213] from IP address 10.109.63.143 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,213] ERROR - AUDIT_LOG Illegal access attempt at [2014-06-10 15:44:41,0213] from IP address 10.109.63.143 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
[2014-06-10 15:44:41,216] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Login failed.Insufficient privileges.
```

Comment: Did you try with Admin user/password?

Comment: What's your datasource? Mysql or H2 or Postgrsql?

Answer (score 0):

If you using default API Manager product without any modification, you should be able to login using admin username and password which is,

- username : admin
- password : admin

HTH,

DarRay

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https, make sure you also add your certificate in clientTrustore.jks (in the same folder as wso2carbon.jks) in addition to wso2carbon.jks as those two components need to use this certificate to talk to other internal services via web service calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default settings without any modifications, 
Username and Password are admin, admin